# Dynamic_casting to a class template parameter is giving an incomplete type error, despite the call being done where the type is complete

Tags: c++, rtti

Here is the code for the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/hK33nP6dT
The snippets below won't be enough, the full problem example code is in [that godbolt link.](https://godbolt.org/z/hK33nP6dT)

Here is the error:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /app/container.h:3,
                 from /app/main.cpp:3:
base.h: In instantiation of 'bool DerivedChecker<T>::IsValid(const BaseClass*) [with T = DerivedClass]':
base.h:13:7:   required from here
base.h:15:10: error: cannot 'dynamic_cast' 'base' (of type 'const struct BaseClass*') to type 'const struct DerivedClass*' (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)
   15 |   return dynamic_cast<const T*>(base) != nullptr;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My overall goal is to pass a `BaseClass*` into the function `IsValid` and attempt to `dynamic_cast` that pointer into some templated type T.  Then it returns true if it was possible to `dynamic_cast` or false if the `dynamic_cast` failed.  I just want to see if the passed in `BaseClass*` pointer is convertible to the templated type T.

The issue is `dynamic_cast` for some reason has an incomplete type, even though I'm making the `IsValid` call from a place in the code that has the complete type.  I want to structure my code so that the `dynamic_cast` does have the complete type, thus removing the error.

I need to declare `DerivedChecker` objects in places where their templated type is forward declared (incomplete), and then call `IsValid` virtually through their base `BaseChecker` in places where the templated type is complete.  So the general idea is forward declared types in various headers being used as the template parameter for `DerivedChecker`:

```
class DerivedClass; //forward declared, incomplete type
BaseChecker* checker = new DerivedChecker<DerivedClass>(); //forward declared type used as template parameter, storing as a pointer to BaseChecker and using a virtual call through it later
```

And then in their respective .cpp files I'm including the headers to complete those types and then making the call to `IsValid`:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {}; //defined, complete class
checker->IsValid(new BaseClass()); //virtual call to DerivedChecker<DerivedClass>::IsValid
```

This must be done in different header files and compilation units; I can't just smash all this stuff into one header/cpp file because `DerivedChecker` will be used in many places with many different templated types.

In my example, I'm using a forward declared `DerivedClass` in `container.h`, that is then fully defined in `container.cpp` right before the virtual call to `DerivedChecker<DerivedClass>::IsValid`.  So when that virtual `IsValid` call is made that goes to `DerivedChecker<DerivedClass>`, `DerivedClass` is fully defined and yet the `dynamic_cast` is still throwing the "target is not pointer or reference to complete type" error.

[In the example code](https://godbolt.org/z/hK33nP6dT), `base.h` contains `BaseChecker` and `DerivedChecker` as well as the `BaseClass` that is taken as a parameter by `IsValid`.

`container.h` is the common use case for `DerivedChecker`: Some class with a `DerivedChecker` field (in this case, the class `Container`), with a forward declaration of the templated type used in `DerivedChecker` (in this case, `DerivedChecker<DerivedClass>` with `DerivedClass` forward declared in `container.h`).

`container.cpp` will hold the function definitions for `container.h` and also all the necessary includes for the forward declared classes in `container.h`.  In this example, I simply defined `DerivedClass` in `container.cpp` rather than make another header file for it and including that.  `Container` has a function defined in `container.cpp` that makes the virtual `IsValid` call, after `DerivedClass` has been fully defined and is a complete class in `container.cpp`.

`main.cpp` simply sets all this up and calls the function.

How can I keep this usage pattern, and structure the code so `dynamic_cast` does have access to the complete type when it is called?

Comment: You need to move the class definition of `DerivedClass` from `container.cpp` to `container.h` to make it visible. Forward declaring it isn't enough.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That solution is obvious but will massively pollute my header files with includes in practice.  I'm looking for a solution that keeps the pattern of forward declaration in headers.

Comment: Well, `main.cpp` includes `container.h` which includes `base.h` so in that translation unit, the definition of `DerivedClass` is unknown. Perhaps you want [`pimpl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)?